# iPad and iframe cookies

Tags: ipad, jsp, cookies, iframe, struts

I am developing a Facebook canvas application using the iframe method, because of existing infrastructure the session data is set in a cookie between each page request (including jQuery JSON requests) this all works fine in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE( with the P3P header being set) but not in MobileSafari on the iPad (iOS 4.2).

I've been watching the debug as each page is loaded and it seems the session isn't being passed through as each page loads.

Does anyone know what it takes to get MobileSafari accepting cookies inside an iframe?

Thanks in advance!
Callum

Comment: did you ever get this working? I'm hitting the exact same issue.

Comment: My solution was to then pass through a state ID as a query string, so each different session would have something like login.do?stateid=sjdnajsdn3eqwdasdasdsajdasndsa2w which would then reference an object in the database that contained the real state date (basically a server side cookie).

Comment: I solved it by doing a POST and setting the cookie in that request.. fixes issues for several broken browsers... as well as setting the P3P headers.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends used this and said it worked

http://anantgarg.com/2010/02/18/cross-domain-cookies-in-safari/

EDIT: updated link

Comment: I have those set on all pages, doesn't seem to have any effect.